# Xamarin, send data between classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

These are my tabbed page. [image]

If I click on the GÖNDER button, I'm going to the SONUÇ page.

When I open the program, my % value in my SONUÇ page is opening %0 by default. I need a set of actions. But the master-detail page opens automatically when the program is opened.

[image]

When I click on the GÖNDER button, the % VALUE on the SONUÇ page changes but I can not show because I can not Reload.

How can I reload or refresh when my SONUÇ page changes % value?

Comment: It's really difficult to tell what your exact issues based on your description and screenshots.  Sharing the relevant portions of the code is usually a good idea.  But fundamentally you can pass values between pages (class) like you do in any app - on the constructor, via public methods or properties, or by using message passing via the XF MessagingCenter

Comment: You can use messagincenter https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/

Answer (score 1):

Might be in this case **MessagingCenter** concept will useful for you in xamarin.forms

**Reference link:**

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/